# Library for rapid development of dynamic programming solutions for board games

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I want to use Python to evaluate a variety of dynamic programming approaches to 2-player board games without uncertainty (such as chess, etc.). I'm interested in both precise and heuristic solutions. My "evaluation" consists of trying each approach and observing how well it does on the test cases I generate.

I'm looking for a very flexible library or a framework that helps me code, evaluate (and debug...) various approaches as quickly and easily as possible.

I only care about asymptotic performance (e.g., `O(n log n)` vs `O(n^2)`, etc.). So I need efficient data structures, but I don't mind a constant-factor performance hit.

I don't mind if it takes some upfront investment of time to learn the library.

I don't need any front-end; I only use command-line interface.

I also don't need parallel / distributed programming support (although I wouldn't refuse it if it's available).

I need the library to support Python 3 either now or very soon.

Are there any libraries that provide such support?

Comment: "Any recommendations" is pretty open-ended, and makes me itch to select that "Not Constructive" close reason since it solicits polling / opinion. You're also stretching it to require Python 3.

Comment: Is there any way to modify it to make it constructive, without losing the gist of my question? I tried a weak attempt at that (see the updated end of the question).

Comment: I don't think so. It's just not a Stack Overflow question. You ask a lot of good questions, so I wanted to give you a chance to come up with something I hadn't thought of. But since the question seems to be just a straight request for recommendations, I'm going to vote to close.

Comment: Yeah... perhaps I should ask instead "What website is appropriate to ask questions like the one below... "? :)

Comment: @agf if it was a question about language or web framework recommendations I might agree with you but given how esoteric the problem space is I think it's fair enough to ask for recommendations.

Comment: @Endophage I'm not saying it's a bad question, but it's still not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @agf however, if you can't recommend a different stackexchange, much like choosing where to ask a Q in IRC, this seems like it would be the most appropriate place for this question as the place it's most likely to get a constructive answer. (of which it now has one already)

Comment: @Endophage There _isn't_ an appropriate Stack Exchange. Some questions don't fit in here. That's by design.

Comment: @agf *shrug* as I said, place most likely to get a constructive answer...

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any library that is specific to dynamic programming.  However, dynamic programming is basically using memoization to speed computing functions, and there is a slick function memoization decorator available as of Python 3.2, called `lru_cache()`.

It's in `functools`, which you should definitely study because it is full of nifty stuff.

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html

`@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=100, typed=False)`

If you need this in some earlier version of Python, there are various memoization recipes available on the web.

Comment: Thanks! And I'm using Python 3.3, so this is perfect! Unfortunately, I need a lot more than this :( I also need support to define and traverse in various ways implicit graphs that represent the state space, to generate and use various scoring functions to guide the traversals, etc. But I will try to at least use `@lru_cache`.